# Using Regex to search for a string that contains "http://" and does not contain "mysite.com"

Tags: html, regex, parsing, dreamweaver

how can I write Regular Rxpression to search for a string that contains "http://" AND does not contain "mysite.com"?

Comment: Something like this might work: ^(http://)((?!mysite\.com).)*$

Comment: This will match `http://www.mysite.com`

Comment: @M42: No it doesn't. I tested it here http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx, YMMV.

Comment: No! please re-read my question Iwant "http://" but NOT "mysite.com"....in a plain english I want to fetch all external links

Comment: No language, I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver editor search where it enables me to search using regexp.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I haven't taken into account the surrounded grouping

Comment: @Cassini: YES! I read your question. Please try some of the solutions people are giving you.

Comment: I don’t know why you’ve made a `(…)+` of the first part. Also, if the user is going to run something like `@all_links = /($pattern)/g` to pull out all the links that aren’t the one he wants, your anchor won’t work. Then again, neither will my pattern be right. I didn’t realize he wanted to pull them out of larger text. Hm.

Comment: @tchrist:Yeah, I don't know why I did that either! Hadn't grabbed my early morning coffee yet.

Comment: @MattBurland I went back, drank three cups of coffee, and now look what I’ve done. :)

Comment: Attempting to rope regexes into boolean logic best accomplished in a proper programming language is a thankless job.  While it is possible to write `/PAT1/ and not /PAT2/` using complex lookaheads so that it is just one pattern, it is a painful task. **You don’t want to do this this way.** Using a real editor like `vi`, you would simple have a confirmation check so you could manually intervene: `:%s/foo/bar/gc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## ***WARNING***

Attempting to rope regexes into boolean logic best accomplished in a proper programming language is a thankless job.  While it is possible to write `/PAT1/ and not /PAT2/` using complex lookaheads so that it is just one pattern, it is a painful task. **You don’t to do it this way!**

You should have explained what you were really doing in the first place — some sort of match operation in a text editor. You didn’t. So you get a general answer that is going to be challenging to adapt to your localized situation.

## Quick Answer

```
(?sx)                 # let dot cross newlines, enable comments & whitspace
(?= .* http://     )  # lookahead assertion for http://
(?! .* mysite\.com )  # lookahead negation  for mysite.com
```

Using Perl syntax, you could stick that (pre-)compiled pattern into a variable for future use this way:

```perl
my $is_valid_rx = qr{
    (?= .* http://     )  # lookahead assertion for http://
    (?! .* mysite\.com )  # lookahead negation  for mysite.com
}sx;                      # /s to cross newlines, /x for comments & whitespace

# then later on…
if ($some_string =~ $is_valid_rx) { 
     # your string has an http blah and lacks a mysite blah
}
```

However, if your goal is to pull out all such links, that isn’t going to help you, because those lookaheads do not tell you where in the string your link occurs.

In that case, it’s a lot easier to write something to pull out the links and then filter out your unwanted cases after that, using two separate regexes instead of trying to make do everything.

```perl
 @all_links = ($some_string =~ m{ https?://\S+ }xg);
 @good_links = grep !/mysite\.com/, @all_links;
```

Note that no attempt is made to match only links that contain valid URL characters, or that there is no accidental trailing punctuation as so often occurs in plain text.

## And now, for a real answer

Note also that if you’re parsing HTML with this, the approach outlined above is just a quick-and-dirty, fast-and-loose, shoot-from-the-hip kind of link extraction. It’s easy to construct valid input that turns up a lot of false positives, and not altogether hard to construct input that produces false negatives, too.

Here, in contrast, is a full program that dumps out all the `<a ...>` and `<img ...>` link address in its URL arguments, and actually does so correctly because it uses a real parser.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# fetchlinks - fetch all <a> and <img> links from listed URL args
# Tom Christiansen <tchrist@perl.com>
# Wed Mar 14 08:03:53 MDT 2012
#
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTML::LinkExtor;
use URI::URL;

die "usage: $0 url ...\n" unless @ARGV;

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    my @links = fetch_wanted_links($arg => qw<a img>);
    for my $link (@links) {
        print "$arg => " if @ARGV > 1;
        print "$link\n";
    }
}

exit;

sub fetch_wanted_links {
    my($url, @wanted) = @_;

    my %wanted;
    @wanted{@wanted} = (1) x @wanted;

    my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    # Set up a callback that collect links of the wanted variety
    my @hits = ();

    # Make the parser.  Unfortunately, we don't know the base yet
    # (it might be different from $url)
    my $parser = new HTML::LinkExtor sub {
       my($tag, %attr) = @_;
       return if %wanted and not $wanted{$tag};
       push @hits, values %attr;
    };

    # Request document and parse it as it arrives
    my $response = $agent->request(
           HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url),
           sub { $parser->parse( $_[0] ) },
    );

    # Expand all image URLs to absolute ones
    my $base = $response->base;
    @hits = map { $_ = url($_, $base)->abs } @hits;
    return @hits;
}
```

If you run it on a URL like this, it gives this accounting of all the anchor and image links:

```
$ perl fetchlinks http://www.perl.org/
http://www.perl.org/
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/camel_head.v25e738a.png
http://www.perl.org/
http://www.perl.org/learn.html
http://www.perl.org/docs.html
http://www.perl.org/cpan.html
http://www.perl.org/community.html
http://www.perl.org/contribute.html
http://www.perl.org/about.html
http://www.perl.org/get.html
http://www.perl.org/get.html
http://www.perl.org/get.html
http://www.perl.org/about.html
http://www.perl.org/learn.html
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/learn.v0e1f83c.png
http://www.perl.org/learn.html
http://www.perl.org/community.html
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/community.v03bf8ce.png
http://www.perl.org/community.html
http://www.perl.org/docs.html
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/docs.v2622a01.png
http://www.perl.org/docs.html
http://www.perl.org/contribute.html
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/cog.v08b9acc.png
http://www.perl.org/contribute.html
http://www.perl.org/dev.html
http://www.perl.org/contribute.html
http://www.perl.org/cpan.html
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/cpan.vdc5be93.png
http://www.perl.org/cpan.html
http://www.perl.org/events.html
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/cal.v705acef.png
http://www.perl.org/events.html
http://www.perl6.org/
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/perl6.v8ff6c63.png
http://www.perl6.org/
http://www.perl.org/dev.html
http://www.perlfoundation.org/
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/icons/onion.vee5cb98.png
http://www.perlfoundation.org/
http://www.cpan.org/
http://search.cpan.org/~jtang/Net-Stomp-0.45/
http://search.cpan.org/~vaxman/Array-APX-0.3/
http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.71/
http://search.cpan.org/~grandpa/Win32-MSI-HighLevel-1.0008/
http://search.cpan.org/~teejay/Catalyst-TraitFor-Component-ConfigPerSite-0.06/
http://search.cpan.org/~jwieland/WebService-Embedly-0.04/
http://search.cpan.org/~mariab/WWW-TMDB-API0.04/
http://search.cpan.org/~teejay/SOAP-Data-Builder-1/
http://search.cpan.org/~dylan/WWW-Google-Translate-0.03/
http://search.cpan.org/~jtbraun/Parse-RecDescent-1.967_008/
http://www.perl.org/get.html
http://www.perl.org/learn.html
http://www.perl.org/docs.html
http://www.perl.org/community.html
http://www.perl.org/events.html
http://www.perl.org/siteinfo.html#sponsors
http://www.yellowbot.com/
http://st.pimg.net/perlweb/images/friends/yellowbot.vcc29f5b.gif
http://www.perl.org/
http://blogs.perl.org/
http://jobs.perl.org/
http://learn.perl.org/
http://dev.perl.org/
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/us/
http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/3.0/us/80x15.png
http://www.perl.org/siteinfo.html
```

For any work for serious than running a quick `grep` over a file to eyeball general results, you need to use a proper parser to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `.` in `mysite.com`.

Comment: I don't know if `thisismysite.com` must match or not, but it'd be safe to add a word-boundary before `mysite`.

Comment: @Qtax And more than that, as it turns out. Thanks.

Comment: @M42 That’s an interesting — and I think, open — question. It depends on what the original querent really needs.

Comment: @M42, in that case some check after would be needed as well, `thisismysite.computer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `/http:\/\/(?!mysite.com)/`(perl style, work also in javascript)

Comment: I'm using Adobe Dreamwaver editor search where it enable me to search using regexp.

Comment: No! please re-read my question Iwant "http://" but NOT "mysite.com"....in a plain english I want to fetch all external links.

Comment: It will NOT match `http://www.mysite.com` because of the (! construct. But I give it a try on jsfiddle and it match `http://plop.mysite.com` for eg. http://jsfiddle.net/nicocube/h3QxS/